# Conexión desde c# hacia mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Authentication to host '127.0.0.1' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password'
>   failed with message: Unknown database 'localhost''

... como soluciono este error? Este es mi código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
namespace conexionb
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnconectar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection();
            conexion.ConnectionString = "Server=127.0.0.1;Database=localhost; Uid=root;Pwd=;SslMode=none";
            conexion.Open();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Errr.. estás usando la base de datos mysql, cierto? El Workbench es un cliente, como tu código

Comment: @Alfabravo lo unico que quiero es que me conecte la base de datos al c#, pero me sale ese error.

Comment: Pues está muy raro que digas que tu BD se llame `Database=localhost`.

Comment: @Alfabravo  si con ese nombre la tenia ya le cambie ya nada

Comment: Y a qué la cambiaste? Ahí debe ir el nombre de la base de datos y el código que pones no es válido claramente porque pones el hostname.

Comment: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'The host 127.0.0.1 does not support SSL connections.'    esto me sale

Comment: "server=127.0.0.1;Database=data1; Uid=root;pwd=123456;"

Answer (score 0):

En tu último comentario muestras que el error es que por defecto, tu cliente usa SSL y la base de datos debe tener ese modo deshabilitado. EN el código de tu pregunta tienes la opción de SSL en none pero tus datos de conexión están errados.

Crea la cadena de conexión (el `ConnectionString`) como indican en la respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086283/mysql-data-mysqlclient-mysqlexception-the-host-localhost-does-not-support-ssl#45108611) en SO en inglés.

Esencialmente, se define así:

```
server={0};user id={1};password={2};persistsecurityinfo=True;port={3};database={4};SslMode=none
```

- 0 (cero) es la IP del servidor o localhost si es local
- 1 es el
  username
- 2 es la contraseña
- 3 es el puerto
- 4 es el nombre de la base
  de datos

**Edito**: Una vez tienes una cadena de conexión válida, tienes ahora un error muy diferente: Tienes MySQL 8, presumo, y ese tiene [un cambio en la autenticación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-net/en/connector-net-news-8-0-11.html) por defecto a un SHA cacheado blabla, que es el error que AHORA te sale.

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Actualizas tu [driver de conexión en C#](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).
2. Cambias la autenticación por defecto de tus usuarios al legacy (no recomendado porque es definitivamente más inseguro). Puedes seguir las instrucciones en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49228443/236345).

Comment: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Authentication to host '127.0.0.1' for user 'root' using method 'caching_sha2_password' failed with message: Unknown database 'data1''   (esto me sale)

Comment: y es en esta linea   .... conexion.Open();     ahi marca una (X)

Comment: @steven Ya edité la respuesta. Te recomiendo igual, acostumbrarte a leer la documentación para encontrar más fácil la solución a estos problemas.

Comment: Yo en su día tuve que instalar 2 conectores para mysql con C#